# Linq check for percentage in where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to check some percent of value in where clause in Linq

following is my code

```
  List<string> v = await context.Categories.Where(w =>(w.id / 2) * 100 == 50)
                             .Select(w => w.id.ToString()).ToListAsync();
```

the problem is there is record that meets the condition but no record is selecting. I tried using `Convert.ToDecimal(w.id/2)` but its not working either.

How can I get the percent checking in where clause? and why the above code not working?

Comment: Rounding error?

Comment: @Daniel in expression above, no error just not selecting the record that it should

Comment: What is the id of the record you say should be valid?

Comment: @Daniel (id=1)/2*100=50

Comment: If id is integer, you need to divide with 2.0 instead of 2

Comment: 1/2 = 0 like I said rounding error

Comment: solved. thanks all

Comment: @Daniel - It's not a rounding error. There's no rounding going on at all. It's integer math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If id is an integer it does supportswhole numbers so 1/2 = 0. You need to force a cast to a double (a type that supports decimal places) before you operate on it.

```
 List<string> v = await context.Categories.Where(w =>(w.id / 2.0) * 100 == 50)
                             .Select(w => w.id.ToString()).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Why do you say "cast it to a decimal" but in your code you don't do that and instead rely on the compiler doing an implicit conversion?

Comment: Integer such that when you divide by `2.0` and multiply by `100.0` you get `50.0`. That would be integer `1` only. Select its string representation; that would be `"1"`. Does the original poster want a `List<>` with a bunch of `"1"`?

Answer (score 3):

How about changing the order of operations....

```
List<string> v = await context.Categories.Where(w => 100 * w.id / 2 == 50)
                             .Select(w => w.id.ToString()).ToListAsync();
```

or

```
List<string> v = await context.Categories.Where(w => 50 * w.id == 50)
                             .Select(w => w.id.ToString()).ToListAsync();
```

or

```
List<string> v = await context.Categories.Where(w => w.id == 1)
                             .Select(w => w.id.ToString()).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, you don't seem to need the calculation:

```
w =>(w.id / 2) * 100 == 50
```

can be written as

```
w => w.id == 1
```

Comment: On a side note, your code produces a `List<string>` where all items are equal to "1" (?)